# Usar caracter ? en consultas sql usando codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL y deseo utilizar el caracter `"?"` debido a que la sintaxis de postgres 9.5 me lo exige,el problema consiste en que codeigniter por defecto usa ese simbolo para reemplazarlo valores en la consulta SQL.

Alguna recomendación?

```
SELECT codigo, descr, ( select count(*) from "mi_tabla_2" where coddoc::jsonb ? codigo and coddep = '100' and codserie = '50' and codsubserie = '25' ) as check
FROM "mi_tabla_1" 
WHERE std = TRUE
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó agregando atributos de PDO antes de ejecutar el query:

```
$query_str = "SELECT codigo, descr, ( select count(*) from \"mi_tabla_2\" where coddoc::jsonb ? codigo and coddep = '100' and codserie = '50' and codsubserie = '25' ) as check FROM \"mi_tabla_1\" WHERE std = TRUE";

$this->db->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->db->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

$query = $this->db->query($query_str);
```

conn_id permite acceder al objeto PDO principal

[Codeigniter: Custom Function Calls](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));
```

[documentacion](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)

Comment: siempre se pide añadir una explicación, poner solo código vuelve a las respuestas de baja calidad